# Having a vector of weak_ptr, want to return a vector of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, vector, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I'm currently working on a big project and I need to use `weak_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr`.

Here is my problem.

I have a class named House with an attribute: `vector<boost::shared_ptr<People>> my_people`.
I want to modify this data member to be `vector<boost::weak_ptr<People>> my_people`.

My getter was

```
vector<boost::shared_ptr<People>>& getPeople() const
{
    return my_people;
}
```

Normally, with a simple `weak_ptr` I can return `my_people.lock();`

But I have a vector and I don't know how to do something like this:

```
vector<boost::shared_ptr<People>>& getPeople() const
{
    for( vector<boost::weak_ptr<People>::iterator it = my_people.begin();
         it != my_people.end();
         ++it)
    {
        (*it).lock();
    }

    return my_people;
}
```

In other words, I want to return my vector of `weak_ptr` but as a vector of `shared_ptr`. Is it possible? Or do I have to return a vector of `weak_ptr` and use `lock()` everywhere I use them?

Comment: Do you really need `weak_ptr` in the first place ?

Answer (score 2):

Your function is a reasonable start:

```
vector<boost::shared_ptr<People>>& getPeople() const
{
    for( vector<boost::weak_ptr<People>::iterator it = my_people.begin();
         it != my_people.end();
         ++it)
    {
        (*it).lock();
    }

    return my_people;
}
```

But calling `(*it).lock()` just creates a `shared_ptr` and throws it away, it doesn't change the type of the vector elements, and you can't return the vector as a different type.

You need to create a vector of the right type, fill it with the shared_ptr objects, and return it:

```
vector<boost::shared_ptr<People>> getPeople() const
{
    vector<boost::shared_ptr<People>> people(my_people.size());
    std::transform(my_people.begin(), my_people.end(), people.begin(),
                   boost::bind(&boost::weak_ptr<People>::lock, _1));
    return people;
}
```

This iterates over each element of `my_people`, calls `lock()` on it, and assigns the result to the corresponding element of `people`.

If you know that `my_people` never contains expired pointers it's even easier:

```
vector<boost::shared_ptr<People>> getPeople() const
{
  vector<boost::shared_ptr<People>> people(my_people.begin(), my_people.end());
  return people;
}
```

This fills the `people` vector by constructing each `shared_ptr` element from a `weak_ptr` element.  The difference is that this version will throw an exception if a `weak_ptr` has expired because the `shared_ptr` constructor throws if passed an expired `weak_ptr`. The version using`transform`  will put an empty `shared_ptr` in the vector if an expired weak_ptr is transformed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **[std::transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/)**

```
 std::vector<std::shared_ptr<People>> temp;
 sharedTargetList.resize(my_people.size());

 //transform into a shared_ptr vector
 std::transform(my_people.begin(),
        my_people.end(),
        temp.begin(), 
        [](std::weak_ptr<People> weakPtr){ return weakPtr.lock(); } 
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
vector<boost::shared_ptr<People>> getPeople() const
{
    vector<boost::shared_ptr<People>> res;
    for( vector<boost::weak_ptr<People>::iterator it = my_people.begin(); 
         it != my_people.end(); ++it)
        res.push_back(it->lock());
    return res;
}
```

Also, you can filter out the null pointers, if you want.

Of course, you cannot return a reference to a local variable so you have to return a copy. You may want to do instead:

```
void getPeople(vector<boost::shared_ptr<People>> &res) const
{
    for( vector<boost::weak_ptr<People>::iterator it = my_people.begin(); 
         it != my_people.end(); ++it)
        res.push_back(it->lock());
}
```

to avoid copying the return vector.

Comment: I thought about that but, I want to do operations on the attribute my_people, not on a copy ?

Comment: @user1747056 then you have to write a function that would take a specific vector element, lock it, modify its pointee.

Comment: Do you mean that the caller can modify (add/delete) the list? If so, I'm afraid that you will need something more complicated than that. For example, you can have a `getPeople()` as in my answer, and then a `setPeople(const vector<boost::shared_ptr<People>> &ps)` that puts back the modified list in the form of a `vector<weak_ptr>`. Then you can wrap the calls to `getPeople/setPeople` using the constructor/destructor of a helper class. But I'd say that you are better going on with the obvious: change the callers to use `weak_ptr`. Or even better, do not let the caller modify the list!

Comment: @rodrigo: the caller often needs to modify the list. I think I'm going to change the callers to use weak_ptr. I guess it's the easiest solution.

Comment: @IgorR. : it will still return a copy, won't it ?

Comment: @user1747056 it won't return anything, it would just modify some vector element in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `vector<weak_ptr<T> >` and `vector<shared_ptr<T> >` are two completely different types.

However, you can write a function that accepts the former and returns the latter:

```
  template<class Ptrs, class WeakPtrs> 
  void lockWeakPtrs(const WeakPtrs &weakPtrs, Ptrs &ptrs)
  {
      BOOST_FOREACH (typename WeakPtrs::const_reference weakPtr, weakPtrs)
      {
          typename Ptrs::value_type ptr = weakPtr.lock();
          if (ptr) // if you want to drop expired weak_ptr's
              ptrs.insert(ptrs.end(), ptr);
      }
  }
```

Call like this:
  `lockWeakPtrs(myWeakVector, mySharedVector);`